# Automatically remove alphabetical leters from textbox? C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Can aphabetical leters be automatically removed from textbox after focus is lost, and let only numeric values stay and point and commas? If yes, please show example

Comment: Is this wpf or winforms? The tags contradict. Either way you can use the focuslost event. Then set the textbox to something like: `test.Text = Regex.Replace(test.Text, "[^0-9.]", "");`

Comment: I'm working with wpf, but I think a answer for winforms can help too

Comment: You can see the LostFocus event

Comment: yes, but i need a code sample or something that can help

Comment: @William can you explain the code a bit please

Comment: I do not think You go the right way. From what you wrote it is clear that letter is wrong input. In that case the user should correct it. When You swallow it silently there can be error that passes unnoticed (like changing 10E3 into 103).

Comment: Thats what i want, to eat the letters and leave only the digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WPF]

Something like this should work:

Hook up the event in xaml:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="test" IsKeyboardFocusedChanged="test_IsKeyboardFocusedChanged"></TextBlock>
```

or code...

```
TextBox test = new TextBox();
test.IsKeyboardFocusedChanged += test_IsKeyboardFocusedChanged;
```

then in the event..

```
void test_IsKeyboardFocusedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var test = sender as TextBox;
    test.Text = Regex.Replace(test.Text, "[^0-9.,]", "");
}
```

The regular expression will replace the non numeric characters with empty empty strings.

Comment: Yes, see this site: http://regexr.com/3aqdu. Just replace the second parameter in Regex.Replace with your regex. The one on the link is or US currency

Comment: I wrote this code to format it for currency 
txbPrice.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"),
                                          "{0:#,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(txbPrice.Text));
... which part should I put in the second parameter?

Comment: You shouldn't need to get the CultureInfo for the formatting. Just replace that line with this one: `tebPrice.Text = Regex.Replace(txbPrice.Text, "[^0-9.,]", "");`

Comment: You'll need to add this to the top: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` also

Comment: txbPrice.Text = Regex.Replace(txbPrice.Text, @"[^\$?-?(((\d{1,3},?)(\d{3},?)+|\d{1,3})|\d+)(\.\d{1,2})?$]", "");
            
this works too :)

Comment: txbPrice.Text = Regex.Replace(txbPrice.Text, "[^0-9.,]", "");
          
  txbPrice.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"),
                                          "{0:#,##0.00}", decimal.Parse(txbPrice.Text));

i leave it like this cuz i need the second code row to format the hundred point, hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a **Windows Forms** control that limits data entry to numeric values without writing code, then it seems you are looking for [`NumericUpdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

The numeric display can be formatted by setting the `DecimalPlaces`, `Hexadecimal`, or `ThousandsSeparator` properties.